# iOS - iPad Air and iPad Pro force device orientation in landscape only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am try to implement iOS app particular view controller always open only landscape mode. i add following code in viewWillAppear.

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

above coding working fine following devices iPhone 4s/5/5s/6/6s and iPad 2/Retina. but iPad Air/Air 2/Pro not working. how to resolve this problem. please guide me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of device orientation Use following in Your ViewController:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: @ jagdish thanks for your reply.. i am also find some work around solution.. i have enable portrait and Requires full screen mode in Target-- device orientation.. then above coding is working good..

Comment: Ok..So this is not what you want.. am i misunderstand your question?